# Issue with redirect syntax in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I get an error with redirects in my conf file in nginx. Before I used this syntax:

```
location = /old-url/ {
  return 301 /new-url/;
}
```

This was no longer working so I adopted the following:

```
rewrite ^/old-url/$
/new-url/ permanent;
```

The second one seemed to be working fine, but now I get an error:

> This page isn’t working  www.my-website.co.uk redirected you too many
>   times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I am new to nginx and not sure which syntax is correct and why the second one is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below currently I didn’t ran it on my side,

```
rewrite ^/old-url/ http://your-site.com/new-url/ permanent;
```